# Avoid disturbing neighbors/roommates ... is a pillow fort effective?

Tags: sound, noise, soundproofing

Does anyone have a good idea on how to reduce the noise I am producing when speaking in my room, so to avoid disturbing my neighbors me. (Without I have to speak lower than usual; i.e. whisper).

I was thinking a pillow fort might be a good idea, do you think it would be effective? 
Any alternative ideas perhaps?

Comment: A small tip: ask your neighbours/roommates to help you test this. If they're at all reasonable they will appreciate that you're trying to be considerate. It may be that you can agree times of day that are less annoying for them, or come to some other arrangement without having to spend a lot of money making your activities completely silent.

Answer (score 2):

**Mass** & **air gapping** prevents sound transmission.

A speaking voice doesn't take much sound insulation to stop it leaking into the next room, but if you live in a building where the walls & doors are so light that you can hear someone speaking normally from the next room with the doors shut, then there's little a bunch of pillows is going to do to help.

As you're starting from such a high-transmission structure I don't think anything short of 4" of heavy rockwool inside another plaster-board [drywall] layer is really going to help much.

For economy of effort … just go outdoors.

BTW, you can easily test how much a pillow will stop sound by getting someone to speak right in front of you, with & without a pillow over their mouth. Muffled, yes - because it will remove the highest frequencies - but any less actual volume… no.